# Raspberry Pi 4 used as BLE central device connection issues

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, bluetooth-lowenergy, bleno

For a professional project, i have to use a RPI4 as a central device to connect to a particular peripheral device.
For testing, I developped a program to simulate a peripheral on a RPi (thanks to bleno Node.js module) by setting a GATT server and use another RPi as my central with the bluepy Python library.

All worked fine but when I set the advertising interval higher than 4000ms on my peripheral, connection doesn't work anymore (even on the RPi GATT server or with the production one).

I tried to use gatttool/hcitool on my central, same issues, it works well but only if advertising interval is less than 4000ms. 
But it works when I try to connect to my GATT server with my phone with a dedicated application (nRF connect).

After some research, I found that the Linux kernel only validates values of connection interval within the range 7.5ms - 4000ms (https://lkml.org/lkml/2019/8/2/358), which match exactly with my experimental values. But except if I don't understand something with BLE, connection interval and advertising interval are totally independent and it should not be a problem. In the Bluetooth documentation, I found that maximum advertising interval value should be 10240ms. There is something I don't understand.

Here is my GATT server running on one RPi4 if you want to reproduce that.
I start it using `sudo BLENO_ADVERTISING_INTERVAL=xxxx node my_gatt_server.js` with xxxx the advertising interval I want in ms.

```
var bleno = require('bleno');

// Once bleno starts, begin advertising our BLE address
bleno.on('stateChange', function(state) {
    console.log('State change: ' + state);
    if (state === 'poweredOn') {
        bleno.startAdvertising('MyDevice',['6d79686561727473656e74696e656c10']);
    } else {
        bleno.stopAdvertising();
    }
});

// Notify the console that we've accepted a connection
bleno.on('accept', function(clientAddress) {
    console.log("Accepted connection from address: " + clientAddress);
});

// Notify the console that we have disconnected from a client
bleno.on('disconnect', function(clientAddress) {
    console.log("Disconnected from address: " + clientAddress);
});

// When we begin advertising, create a new service and characteristic
bleno.on('advertisingStart', function(error) {
    if (error) {
        console.log("Advertising start error: " + error);
    } else {
        console.log("Advertising start success");
        bleno.setServices([

            // Define a new service
            new bleno.PrimaryService({
                uuid : '6d79686561727473656e74696e656c10',
                characteristics : [

                    // ECG characteristic
                    new bleno.Characteristic({
                        value : 'hello!',
                        uuid : '6d79686561727473656e74696e656c11',
                        properties : ['read'],

                        // Send a message back to the client with the characteristic's value
                        onReadRequest : function(offset, callback) {
                            console.log("Read request received");
                            callback(this.RESULT_SUCCESS, new Buffer("Echo: " + this.value);
                        }
                    })
                ]
            }), 
        ]);
    }
});
```

HCI packets logs

When connection succeeded

```
Bluetooth monitor ver 5.50
= Note: Linux version 4.19.57-v7l+ (armv7l)                                                                                                                                                                                         0.501891
= Note: Bluetooth subsystem version 2.22                                                                                                                                                                                            0.501900
= New Index: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (Primary,UART,hci0)                                                                                                                                                                           [hci0] 0.501905
= Open Index: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx                                                                                                                                                                                              [hci0] 0.501908
= Index Info: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (Cypress Semiconductor Corporation)                                                                                                                                                          [hci0] 0.501911
@ MGMT Open: bluetoothd (privileged) version 1.14                                                                                                                                                                          {0x0001} 0.501915
@ MGMT Open: btmon (privileged) version 1.14                                                                                                                                                                               {0x0002} 0.501989
< HCI Command: LE Set Scan Parameters (0x08|0x000b) plen 7                                                                                                                                                                #1 [hci0] 4.586280
        Type: Passive (0x00)
        Interval: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
        Window: 30.000 msec (0x0030)
        Own address type: Public (0x00)
        Filter policy: Ignore not in white list (0x01)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                                                                                                                                               #2 [hci0] 4.586656
      LE Set Scan Parameters (0x08|0x000b) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) plen 2                                                                                                                                                                    #3 [hci0] 4.586717
        Scanning: Enabled (0x01)
        Filter duplicates: Enabled (0x01)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                                                                                                                                               #4 [hci0] 4.587132
      LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 33                                                                                                                                                                                 #5 [hci0] 4.619942
      LE Advertising Report (0x02)
        Num reports: 1
        Event type: Connectable undirected - ADV_IND (0x00)
        Address type: Public (0x00)
        Address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (OUI DC-A6-32)
        Data length: 21
        Flags: 0x06
          LE General Discoverable Mode
          BR/EDR Not Supported
        128-bit Service UUIDs (partial): 1 entry
          Vendor specific (6d796865-6172-7473-656e-74696e656c10)
        RSSI: -31 dBm (0xe1)
< HCI Command: LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) plen 2                                                                                                                                                                    #6 [hci0] 4.620014
        Scanning: Disabled (0x00)
        Filter duplicates: Disabled (0x00)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                                                                                                                                               #7 [hci0] 4.621661
      LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Create Connection (0x08|0x000d) plen 25                                                                                                                                                                 #8 [hci0] 4.621724
        Scan interval: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
        Scan window: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
        Filter policy: White list is not used (0x00)
        Peer address type: Public (0x00)
        Peer address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (OUI DC-A6-32)
        Own address type: Public (0x00)
        Min connection interval: 30.00 msec (0x0018)
        Max connection interval: 50.00 msec (0x0028)
        Connection latency: 0 (0x0000)
        Supervision timeout: 420 msec (0x002a)
        Min connection length: 0.000 msec (0x0000)
        Max connection length: 0.000 msec (0x0000)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                                                                                                                                                                                 #9 [hci0] 4.622251
      LE Create Connection (0x08|0x000d) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 19                                                                                                                                                                                #10 [hci0] 4.726113
      LE Connection Complete (0x01)
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 64
        Role: Master (0x00)
        Peer address type: Public (0x00)
        Peer address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (OUI DC-A6-32)
        Connection interval: 48.75 msec (0x0027)
        Connection latency: 0 (0x0000)
        Supervision timeout: 420 msec (0x002a)
        Master clock accuracy: 0x00
@ MGMT Event: Device Connected (0x000b) plen 34                                                                                                                                                                     {0x0002} [hci0] 4.726162
        LE Address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (OUI DC-A6-32)
        Flags: 0x00000000
        Data length: 21
        Flags: 0x06
          LE General Discoverable Mode
          BR/EDR Not Supported
        128-bit Service UUIDs (partial): 1 entry
          Vendor specific (6d796865-6172-7473-656e-74696e656c10)
@ MGMT Event: Device Connected (0x000b) plen 34                                                                                                                                                                     {0x0001} [hci0] 4.726162
        LE Address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (OUI DC-A6-32)
        Flags: 0x00000000
        Data length: 21
        Flags: 0x06
          LE General Discoverable Mode
          BR/EDR Not Supported
        128-bit Service UUIDs (partial): 1 entry
          Vendor specific (6d796865-6172-7473-656e-74696e656c10)
< HCI Command: LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) plen 2                                                                                                                                                         #11 [hci0] 4.726356
        Handle: 64
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                                                                                                                                                                                #12 [hci0] 4.726943
      LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 14                                                                                                                                                                             #13 [hci0] 4.726951
      LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                    ..........      
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 12                                                                                                                                                                                #14 [hci0] 4.881359
      LE Read Remote Used Features (0x04)
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 64
        Features: 0x3f 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
          LE Encryption
          Connection Parameter Request Procedure
          Extended Reject Indication
          Slave-initiated Features Exchange
          LE Ping
          LE Data Packet Length Extension
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 11                                                                                                                                                                                #15 [hci0] 5.027630
      LE Data Length Change (0x07)
        Handle: 64
        Max TX octets: 251
        Max TX time: 2120
        Max RX octets: 251
        Max RX time: 2120
```

When connection failed

```
Bluetooth monitor ver 5.50
= Note: Linux version 4.19.57-v7l+ (armv7l)                                                                                                                                                                                         0.114663
= Note: Bluetooth subsystem version 2.22                                                                                                                                                                                            0.114671
= New Index: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (Primary,UART,hci0)                                                                                                                                                                           [hci0] 0.114675
= Open Index: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx                                                                                                                                                                                              [hci0] 0.114678
= Index Info: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (Cypress Semiconductor Corporation)                                                                                                                                                          [hci0] 0.114681
@ MGMT Open: bluetoothd (privileged) version 1.14                                                                                                                                                                          {0x0001} 0.114686
@ MGMT Open: btmon (privileged) version 1.14                                                                                                                                                                               {0x0002} 0.114760
< HCI Command: Disconnect (0x01|0x0006) plen 3                                                                                                                                                                            #1 [hci0] 5.864108
        Handle: 64
        Reason: Remote User Terminated Connection (0x13)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                                                                                                                                                                                 #2 [hci0] 5.864469
      Disconnect (0x01|0x0006) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: Disconnect Complete (0x05) plen 4                                                                                                                                                                            #3 [hci0] 5.883803
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 64
        Reason: Remote User Terminated Connection (0x13)
@ MGMT Event: Device Disconnected (0x000c) plen 8                                                                                                                                                                   {0x0002} [hci0] 5.883848
        LE Address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (OUI DC-A6-32)
        Reason: Connection terminated by remote host (0x03)
@ MGMT Event: Device Disconnected (0x000c) plen 8                                                                                                                                                                   {0x0001} [hci0] 5.883848
        LE Address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (OUI DC-A6-32)
        Reason: Connection terminated by remote host (0x03)
< HCI Command: LE Set Scan Parameters (0x08|0x000b) plen 7                                                                                                                                                               #4 [hci0] 25.059876
        Type: Passive (0x00)
        Interval: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
        Window: 30.000 msec (0x0030)
        Own address type: Public (0x00)
        Filter policy: Ignore not in white list (0x01)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                                                                                                                                              #5 [hci0] 25.060698
      LE Set Scan Parameters (0x08|0x000b) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) plen 2                                                                                                                                                                   #6 [hci0] 25.060762
        Scanning: Enabled (0x01)
        Filter duplicates: Enabled (0x01)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                                                                                                                                              #7 [hci0] 25.061665
      LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 33                                                                                                                                                                                #8 [hci0] 39.473657
      LE Advertising Report (0x02)
        Num reports: 1
        Event type: Connectable undirected - ADV_IND (0x00)
        Address type: Public (0x00)
        Address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (OUI DC-A6-32)
        Data length: 21
        Flags: 0x06
          LE General Discoverable Mode
          BR/EDR Not Supported
        128-bit Service UUIDs (partial): 1 entry
          Vendor specific (6d796865-6172-7473-656e-74696e656c10)
        RSSI: -28 dBm (0xe4)
< HCI Command: LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) plen 2                                                                                                                                                                   #9 [hci0] 39.473746
        Scanning: Disabled (0x00)
        Filter duplicates: Disabled (0x00)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                                                                                                                                             #10 [hci0] 39.475900
      LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Create Connection (0x08|0x000d) plen 25                                                                                                                                                               #11 [hci0] 39.475956
        Scan interval: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
        Scan window: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
        Filter policy: White list is not used (0x00)
        Peer address type: Public (0x00)
        Peer address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (OUI DC-A6-32)
        Own address type: Public (0x00)
        Min connection interval: 30.00 msec (0x0018)
        Max connection interval: 50.00 msec (0x0028)
        Connection latency: 0 (0x0000)
        Supervision timeout: 420 msec (0x002a)
        Min connection length: 0.000 msec (0x0000)
        Max connection length: 0.000 msec (0x0000)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                                                                                                                                                                               #12 [hci0] 39.476993
      LE Create Connection (0x08|0x000d) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Create Connection Cancel (0x08|0x000e) plen 0                                                                                                                                                         #13 [hci0] 43.544123
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                                                                                                                                             #14 [hci0] 43.546763
      LE Create Connection Cancel (0x08|0x000e) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 19                                                                                                                                                                               #15 [hci0] 43.546914
      LE Connection Complete (0x01)
        Status: Unknown Connection Identifier (0x02)
        Handle: 64
        Role: Master (0x00)
        Peer address type: Public (0x00)
        Peer address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (OUI DC-A6-32)
        Connection interval: 48.75 msec (0x0027)
        Connection latency: 0 (0x0000)
        Supervision timeout: 420 msec (0x002a)
        Master clock accuracy: 0x00
```

When it fails, gatttool output error is `Error: connect error: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4000 ms is a quite large advertising interval. Anyway, bluepy uses BlueZ, and when BlueZ connects, it first scans and when it finds the wanted device, it stops scanning and initiates a connection. During this connection attempt, there is a timeout before starting scanning again. It could be that this 4000 ms advertising interval is larger than the timeout. It's commonly 2 seconds I think.

Please start "sudo btmon" on your central device before attempting to connect, let it capture and print the HCI packets and post the output here.

Advertising interval and Connection interval are completely independent.

Comment: Tanks for your response @Emil, that's what I guessed. But it can't be 2sec because it works when I set advertising interval to 4000ms exactly but not with higher value like I said. I will post my HCI outputs here!

Comment: I know 4sec is quite large but for my purpose, I really need to advertise the less I can to save energy, because I have high energy constraints on my peripheral.
If it's really a BlueZ issue, is there any way to increase this time out ?

Comment: Ok so it was recently increased to 4 seconds apparently. That can also be observed by looking at your failed log. See https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/include/net/bluetooth/hci.h?id=1f01d8be0e6a04bd682a55f6d50c14c1679e7571. You can increase it and recompile the kernel if you want. HCI_LE_AUTOCONN_TIMEOUT is by the way used here: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/net/bluetooth/hci_event.c.